# "The" or "an" official language

Tags: articles

India has more than one official language.

Which variant is correct?

> "What is **the/an** official language of India?"

Comment: **a** suggests there is more than one, which, in fact there is in India's case. I understand this is tricky for Slavic language speakers but really, this is very basic. An official language=there is more than one; the *official language or language**s** of the country*.

Comment: So, If there are two languages in a country, I should say "What are official languages of Canada?" not What are the official languages of Canada?"

Comment: Nope. What are "the official languages of Canada". See  my comment above: the "the" applies to both.

Comment: [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_India) *Article 343 of the Indian Constitution stated that **the** official **language** [singular] of the Union is Hindi in Devanagari script*. English is just ***another*** official language. As Wikipedia says, *a constitutional amendment, The Official Languages Act, 1963, allowed for the continuation of English alongside Hindi in the Indian government **indefinitely until legislation decides to change it*** - but "officially, politically", English is definitely "secondary".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Of course, the official language [of a country] UNLESS there is more than one.

Comment: @Lambie: The entire *concept* of "official language" doesn't really make much sense unless there are (or at least, reasonably *could* be) more than one potential candidate. Lots of official documents in the UK are routinely available in languages other than English (Hindi, for example, as well as "local" alternatives like Welsh). But it's hard to imagine why anyone would ever say anything like *English is the "official" language of the UK*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is not the point, is it? Use: the official reason for something; an official reason for something.

Comment: @Olga: It's essentially just a stylistic choice whether to include the article when asking *What are [the] official languages of India?* It just so happens that in that *exact* context, almost all native Anglophones would almost always choose to include ***the***. Which they *wouldn't* normally do with, say, *What are good ways to learn English?*, but the relevant underlying syntax is the same in both cases. Also note that in both cases, if we reduce the question to asking about a *singular* entity, you *must* include ***a*** or ***the*** (*What is good way to learn?* is *not* good! :)

Answer (score 4):

As a question, both "a" and "the" are correct.

You would use "the language" if you believed that there was only one, and you want to know what it is.  The answer to that question could be

> Actually India has many official languages, including Hindi and English.

You would use "a language" if you believed that there are many, and you want to know a single example. The answer to that question could be:

> Hindi.

You would use a plural question "What are the official languages of India if you wanted to know them all.

It is correct to use "the language" because it is possible to believe that there is only one official language.  If you know that there are many, you would use "a" or a plural question.

Similarly you can ask "What is the official language of the UK" and the answer could be "There is no official language (though English is widely spoken and Welsh is official in Wales)"

It is grammatically correct to ask a question that has no answer. After all, if you know the answer, why do you need to ask the question?

Comment: Certainly not exhaustive, but comprehensive. I like your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask, "What is the official language of India?" then you assume that India has only one official language.

You should ask, "What is an official language of India?" only if you think that it has multiple official languages or you're not sure about how many it has.

Note that in both cases, "language" is singular, so an accurate reply would mention only one language.

Comment: You can't ask it, if you don't know it. Most countries have one official language. The answer is then adjusted. It has one official language or two official languages.